# Binding updating after State in SwiftUI, triggering 2 updates

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've noticed that if a `Binding` and a `State` are changed in the same `withAnimation` block, the `State` will be updated first, trigger a redraw, and then the `Binding` will be updated, triggering a second redraw. When instead of a `Binding`, I use two `State` variables, then the redraw happens just once and both values are updated at the same time:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Binding var x1: Int
//    @State var x1: Int
    @State var x2: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    x1 += 1
                    x2 += 2
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Increment")
                    .padding()
            })
            Text("Total: \(total)")
        }
    }
    
    var total: Int {
        print("\(x1) + \(x2) = \(x1 + x2)")
        return x1 + x2
    }
}
```

When hitting the button, the console prints:

```
0 + 2 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
```

If I switch and use two `State` variables, I only see one print:

```
1 + 2 = 3
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to keep using a `Binding` and a `State` but trigger a redraw just once?

#### Edit

Xcode 12.2, iOS 14.2
[image]

#### Edit 2

Xcode 12.1, iOS 14.1
[image]

Comment: I just have it in the `App`. I know it doesn’t make sense for this example but it does in other cases. Imagine a `View` whose layout changes depending on some state variables and a binding. The binding is to manually update that view layout from a container

Comment: I’m using Xcode 12.2 and a simulator with iOS 14.2 but I’ve seen it in previous versions. The binding is bound a state variable in a container `@State var x1 = 0` that’s then passed using its projected value `ContentView(x1: $x1)`

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't think this can't be reproduced (see Edit)